# VBA: need decide if result of FIND method is NOTHING or "" (empty)

Tags: vba, excel

I have this

```
Set rngFound = Selection.Find(What:=Trim(prirustek.Cells(i, 1).Value), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

and need to do somethng like this:

```
If rngFound Is Nothing Or rngFound = "" Then
...
```

but this code stops with "Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)". I think this problem is in rngFound that is Nothing, but how can I make

```
rngFound = ""
```

in IF statement?

Comment: Since you know what you're looking for, why not check that before doing the Find()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one `If IIf(rng Is Nothing, "", rng) = "" Then`

It deals with the whole `nothing` situation first. This is kind of like `Nz()` in Access.

Comment: I would not use `Iif()` here, since it doesn't short-circuit: both the second and third arguments are evaluated regardless of the first argument. Try this in the immediate pane: `? IIf(true,"True",1/0)` - you will get a "division by zero error". You should use the longer `If...Else...End If`

Comment: @TimWilliams I hear what you're saying but here it doesn't seem to be an issue. `rng` being `nothing` doesn't cause an error. The only the to be vigilant of is `Dim`ing `rng`. So long as you have `Option Explicit` set you should not have an error in this situation. Your right to say that liberal use of `IIf` should be discouraged though.

Comment: `Dim r As Range:MsgBox IIf(r Is Nothing, "nothing", r.Value)` throws an error for me - "object variable not set". `Is Nothing` doesn't check for declaration - it checks for assignment.

Comment: That's ok though because that's not what this `IIf` is doing. Yes `.value` can't be called but that situation doesn't arise in this `IIf`. I avoided calling `rng.value` here. Once he's inside this `If` block it's up to him. But I can't see how the code I supplied will throw an error.

Comment: @Brad Gah! - you are correct - if you leave off the .Value then it doesn't error. My bad. Since `.Value` is the default property I expected the two versions (implicit/explicit) to behave the same way...  Should have tested of course.

Comment: @TimWilliams No problem, keep me on my toes :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `If rngFound Is Nothing Or rngFound.Value = "" Then`

Comment: **rngFound.Value = ""** not working because **rngFound** is Nothing. I think

Comment: Same problem as IIf() - `rngFound.Value` gets evalulated whether or not rngFound is Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Private Function isRangeEmptyOrNothing(r As Range) As Boolean

  If r Is Nothing Then
    isRangeEmptyOrNothing = True
  ElseIf IsEmpty(r) Then
    isRangeEmptyOrNothing = True
  ElseIf r = "" Then 'Not sure if this is redundant with IsEmpty
    isRangeEmptyOrNothing = True
  End If

End Function
```

Then in your main code:

```
If isRangeEmptyOrNothing(rngFound) Then
```

Comment: IsEmpty() only really works with Variants.  `Dim o as object: debug.print IsEmpty(o)` >> False

Comment: It seemed to work with ranges when I tried, but could probably be removed without changing the outcome...

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
If rngFound = Empty Then ...
```

or

```
If isNull(rngFound) = true Then ...
```

Comment: not working. rngFound may be Nothing and I need to decide this state