# My range.find() is empty

Tags: vba, error-handling, find

I searched for the answer to this question, and came VERY CLOSE with

[VBA: need decide if result of FIND method is NOTHING or "" (empty)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707731/vba-need-decide-if-result-of-find-method-is-nothing-or-empty)

but I couldn't quite understand how to fix my problem. It is pretty much the same, I am using find to look up something in another workbook, and if the find() can't find what I'm looking for, it throws an error. I tried the suggestions in the link above, but I agree with https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams that since my object is still empty, that the IIF() will error still.

```
    Do Until Row > LastRow
       On Error GoTo MFGPNError
       PLRow = Workbooks(WB2).Sheets("5727").Range("C:C").Find(what:=Workbooks(WB1).Main.Cells(Row, 2).Value2, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True).row

    VREFLookup:
       On Error GoTo VREFError
       PLRow = Workbooks(WB2).Sheets("5727").Range("D:D").Find(what:=Workbooks(WB1).Main.Cells(Row, 2).Value2, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True).row
```

Then my error trapping:

```
    Exit Sub
    MFGPNError:
    If PLRow Is Empty Then
       Workbooks(WB1).Main.Cells(Row, 3) = ""
    'If IIf(PLRow Is Empty, "", PLRow) = "" Then
    'setting MPN to be "" and moving to VREF lookup    
    On Error GoTo -1
    GoTo VREFLookup
    End If
    '-----
    Exit Sub
    VREFError:
    If IIf(PLRow Is Nothing, "", PLRow) = "" Then
    'setting MPN to be "" and then adding cleaned up pn to array?
    WB1.Main.Cells(Row, 3) = ""
    On Error GoTo -1
    GoTo CleanPN
    End If
```

On my first Error Trap, I commented out the IIF() because it threw an error, and tried a regular IF(), still an error..

My question is, how can I keep going through my macro, if my Find() throws an error? I would like to just skip that particular Find(), and move on to the next row.

Also, is my error-handling any good? I've never really had to do much of it (mainly do to my macros being very simple)

Comment: What type of variable is `PLRow`? I see what the problem(s) are.

Comment: PLRow was dimmed as Long

Comment: OK. So let's see if I understand... What you are trying to do is look up a value in Column C, if it is not found in column C, then try to look it up in column D?

Comment: Correct. Then if that second find() fails, I'll be doing an entirely different thing which I know how to do.. haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your problem: the result of the `.Find` method is a range object, which can be `Nothing`.  You are trying to evaluate `Nothing.Row` which raises an error.

Rather than deal with messy error handlers and confusing `GoTo` statements, it's best to simply trap that error and deal with it properly.

First, declare a range object and use that to return the result of the `.Find`.

```
Dim rngFound as Range
'## Attempt the lookup in Column C:
Set rngFound = Workbooks(WB2).Sheets("5727").Range("C:C").Find( _
                   what:=Workbooks(WB1).Main.Cells(Row, 2).Value2, _
                   lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True)
```

Then, you can deal with this `rngFound` variable, and test whether it's `Nothing`.  If it is, then do another `Find` against column D:

```
'## If not found, look for it in column D:
If rngFound Is Nothing Then 
    Set rngFound = Workbooks(WB2).Sheets("5727").Range("D:D").Find( _
                   what:=Workbooks(WB1).Main.Cells(Row, 2).Value2, _
                   lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True)

End If
```

If the second find also fails, then you do something else which you already know how to do:

```
If rngFound Is Nothing Then
    '## DO SOMETHING ELSE ##
End If
```

Then, you can assign to your `PLRow` variable

```
If rngFound Is Nothing then
    PLRow = Empty   '## Or modify as needed.
Else: 
    PLRow = rngFound.Row
End If
```

As a best practice, you should avoid using `On Error GoTo...` statements whenever possible, especially when the error can be suitably trapped without an error handler.  Also, within your error handlers (if you absolutely must use them for some other reason), you should probably do `Err.Clear` and also `Resume Next` instead of `GoTo VREFLookup`.

Comment: Ahh.. I see now. Thank you for explaining this! They talked about this in the other thread, but I couldn't follow exactly what they meant.

Comment: Also thanks for the tips about error handling and GoTo's

Comment: Quick thing..  I copied your first code block, and I'm getting a mismatch error on this?

Comment: Variables `WB1` and `WB2` are string? Also, verify that `Main` is a valid sheet codename in `Workbooks(wb1)`.  My want to use `.Value` instead of `.Value2` property, also.  I mean, I kind of assumed that the `Find` method that you had was working, but only sometimes raised errors if the result was `Nothing`.  I didn't modify those code at all...

Comment: You're right. My WB2 variable is jacked up. Thanks again David. I'd give you more rep, but I don't know how.. =/

Comment: I don't need the rep :)